# Symfony 2 Datetime field in Forms

Tags: forms, datetime, symfony

I'm building my form as follow:

```
$builder->add('taskDate', 'datetime', array(
                  'required'=>false,
                  'label'=>'Termin',
                  'input'=>'datetime',
                  'widget'=>'single_text',
                  'attr'=>array('style'=>'max-width: 150px;')
              ))
```

And I got this,

```
2014-02-01T20:00:00+01:00
```

How can I get "normal" Datetime format like what I have in my SQL database?

In my database it's saved as follow: `2014-02-01 20:00:00`.

So, why do I have `T` letter and `+01:00` at the end?

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html#reference-forms-type-date-format

Answer (score 3):

Check the [`date_format`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/datetime.html#date-format) option of the [Datetime Field Type](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/reference/forms/types/datetime.html):

```
date_format:
type: integer or string default: IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM
Defines the format option that will be passed down to the date field.
```

See the [date type's format](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html#reference-forms-type-date-format) option for more details.