# Symfony datetime field format

Tags: symfony, datetime

I have a datetime field in a form which I want to give format mask `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi`, and I use the following code:

```
$builder->add('beginDate', 'datetime', array('widget' => 'single_text',
                                               'date_format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd  HH:i'))
```

But what I get in form field is something like this:

> 2014-08-25T22:37:37Z

I would like something like:

> 2014-08-25 22:37

Can I get this?

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19451469/symfony-2-datetime-field-in-forms) and [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html#reference-forms-type-date-format) but didn't find a real example for hours (24 hour format) and minutes

thank you

Answer (score 13):

Have you tried the following `date_format` in your datetime definition?

```
'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'
```

instead of what you have now:

```
'yyyy-MM-dd HH:i'
```

I think you're mixing PHP date format options with the RFC format options the symfony form builder expects, according to the documentation. Peruse the accepted RFC [datetime formats](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime#TOC-Date-Time-Format-Syntax) to see how to tweak it.

Comment: same result: `2014-08-13T00:00:00Z`

Comment: Given that the output includes seconds and timezone offset, clearly the format definition isn't registering properly. Perhaps it's not a valid format for the single_text widget mode and symfony is falling back to a predefined default, or maybe it's a cache issue. You can clear your cache to see if that produces the expected output format. `php app/console cache:clear`.

Answer (score 11):

You should use the [format option](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/datetime.html#format) which accepts [HTML5 DateTime format](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_time_datetime.asp).

```
$builder->add(
    'beginDate',
    'datetime',
    array(
        'widget' => 'single_text',
        'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd  HH:mm'
    )
)
```

The `format` option should be used instead of `date_format` when using `widget = single_text`.

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you try this?

```
    $builder
        ->add('beginDate', 'date', array(
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd H:mm',
        ));
```

Answer (score 1):

How did you form displays for this result, with Twig or Php ?
Maybe it's about maybe it is in relation to your local in `parameters.yml` et `config.yml` otherwise the twig display.

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/date.html#timezone

Comment: I finally got it to accept my format ('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm') at input though it still shows the T and Z or a +2:00 for timezone when showing a value. This is my final code: `$builder->add('fechaInicio', 'datetime', array('widget' => 'single_text', 'date_format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd  HH:mm', 'model_timezone' => 'Europe/Madrid', 'view_timezone' => 'Europe/Madrid', 'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss')))`

Comment: That link you send sounds nice, but the problem now is, how do I set format mask for a form item **value**? This fails as it tries to apply format mask to all input element: `{{ form_widget(edit_form.fechaInicio)|date("Y-m-d H:i:s", "Europe/Madrid") }}`

Answer (score 0):

Have you try something like this:

```
$builder->add('beginDate', 'datetime', array(
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            // input format for single_text
            'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy kk:mm',
        ));
```

reference to this:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/datetime.html
and this:
http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime#TOC-Date-Time-Format-Syntax

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Problem and this is what worked for me

```
        ->add('closingDate', DateTimeType::class, [
            'date_widget' => 'single_text',
            'date_format' => 'dd.MM.yyyyTH:i',
            'html5' => false,
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This way works for me very well

use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;

```
->add('beginDate', DateType::class, array(
                "widget" => 'single_text',
                "format" => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
                "data" => new \DateTime()
            ))
```